# Yii Indirect modification of overloaded property

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

```
$winnerBid = Bids::model()->find($criteria);
```

Model has next relations:

```
public function relations() {
        return array(
            'item' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Goods', 'item_id'),
            'room' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Rooms', 'room_id'),
            'seller' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RoomPlayers', 'seller_id'),
            'buyer' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'RoomPlayers', 'buyer_id'),
        );
    }
```

When I am trying to save:

```
 $this->seller->current_item++;
    $this->seller->wins++;
    $this->seller->save();
```

I am getting error:

> Indirect modification of overloaded
>   property Bids::$seller has no effect
>   (/var/www/auction/www/protected/models/Bids.php:16)

**But it was everything fine at another server?
How to fix it? Or override php directives? Any ideas? TNX**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem here is that `$seller` is not a "real" property (Yii implements properties on its Models by using the magic `__get` method), so in effect you are trying to modify the return value of a function (which has no effect). It is as if you tried to do:

```
function foo() {
    return 42;
}

// INVALID CODE FOR ILLUSTRATION
(foo())++;
```

I 'm not sure about the status of this behavior on different PHP versions, but there is an easy workaround you can use:

```
$seller = $this->seller;
$seller->current_item++;
$seller->wins++;
$seller->save();
```

Comment: Tnx, for response. but now I am getting Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save() in /var/www/auction/www/protected/models/Bids.php on line 1

Comment: @Joeeee: Then `$this->seller` is not the object it should be -- clearly it should be some subclass of `CActiverRecord`, but it's not (possibly it is `null`). You will need to look into that.

Comment: @joeeee

Couple ways to correct this...


a) Don't be lazy: `$this->seller->current_item = $this->seller->current_item + 1;`

b) Use `setAttribute`: `$this->seller->setAttribute( $this->seller->current_item + 1 )`

c) Use AR's counter thing: $this->seller->updateCounters(array('current_item'=>1,'wins'=>1))

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I was also having the error message **"Yii Indirect modification of overloaded property"** when trying to massively manipulate attributes using the CActiveRecord attributes property.

Then, I discovered another method to overcome this issue, in a case where the magic method is related to an object variable which contains an array take a look: you create an AUXILIARY ARRAY in which you put the original and the new values (sometimes one wants to REPLACE a value related to one of the keys, and these methods are not satisfactory). And AFTERWARDS use an assignation, which works like the reference. For example:

```
$auxiliary_array = array();
foreach(Object->array_built_with_magic as $key=>$value) {
     if(….) {
      $auxiliary_array[$key] = Object->array_built_with_magic[$key];
      } else if (…) {
      $auxiliary_array[$key] = $NEW_VALUE
      }
}
//So now we have the array $auxiliary_array with the
// desired MIX (that is, some originals, some modifications)
//So we will do now:
Object->array_built_with_magic =$auxiliary_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on yii when upgrade to php8.1,
it was in `createCommand()` method.

and it didn't complain in former version of php, that we access a property on model which hasn't been initialized.

the workaround was to change the `bindParam()` method to the `bindValue()`.

because the former wanted to use corresponding database field which has not been initialized yet.
but the later (`bindParam`) just insert the value in the sql statement.