# PHP notice when binding overloaded property in PDOStatement::bindParam

Tags: php, pdo

When I try to bind overloaded property in PDOStatement::bindParam method,

```
$stmt->bindParam(':'.$field.'', $this->$field, $pdoparam);
...

public function __get($param)
    {
        if(isset($this->$param))
            return $this->$param;
    }
```

I get a notice

```
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Msgs::$posttime has no effect in ...
```

After some research I found a bug report about the similar [problem](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39449) at php.net. The proposed solution is to add a & before __get definition.

```
&__get(...
```

But when I try to do that I get another notice

```
Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference in ...
```

PHP version is 5.3.8.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: We need more code, we have no idea what $posttime does and what the function get has to do with anything..

Comment: Sorry, I've posted this comment by mistake.

Comment: For which code do you get that other message?

Comment: foreach ($this->modelfields as $field => $type)    {
    $pdoparam = (stripos($type, 'int') === 0) ? PDO::PARAM_INT : PDO::PARAM_STR;
    $stmt->bindValue(':'.$field.'', $this->$field, $pdoparam);
    }
$this->modelfields property contains an array of table's fields (key) and their types (value),
$this->$field - korresponding value that should be inserted in that field. Everything works fine as long as there is defined value but in some cases there is no value to insert (for example if that fild has to be filled with it's default value). In that case I get the before-mentioned notice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PDOStatement::bindParam` requires a reference and potentially modifies the argument that was passed to it (converts it to the most appropriate type, or writes the result to it if it's an OUT/INOUT parameter).

`PDOStatement::bindValue` doesn't take a reference and doesn't modify the argument.

`__get` returns the value of `$this->$param` but doesn't actually make it a reference to the `$this->$param`, and making a reference to the returned value produces this notice. It is not specific to PDO, even a simple `$x =& $this->$param` will trigger the same notice. **Use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam` to avoid this.**

Some more explanation about a non-reference `__get`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337433/1233508

Answer (score 0):

If you did change your code to `&__get(...`, I think you should also change the following line:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':'.$field.'', &$this->$field, $pdoparam);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. This way I get one notice more. "Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in..."

Comment: Did you try to use a temporary variable? Something like "$temp = &$this->$field; $stmt->bindParam(':'.$field.'', $temp, $pdoparam);"